# Erasing multiple objects from a std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Here is my issue, lets say I have a std::vector with ints in it.

let's say it has 50,90,40,90,80,60,80.

I know I need to remove the second, fifth and third elements. I don't necessarily always know the order of elements to remove, nor how many. The issue is by erasing an element, this changes the index of the other elements. Therefore, how could I erase these and compensate for the index change. (sorting then linearly erasing with an offset is not an option)

Thanks

Comment: "sorting then linearly erasing with an offset is not an option": Why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am offering several methods:

**1. A fast method that does not retain the original order of the elements:**

Assign the current last element of the vector to the element to erase, then erase the last element. This will avoid big moves and all indexes except the last will remain constant. If you start erasing from the back, all precomputed indexes will be correct.

```
void quickDelete( int idx )
{
  vec[idx] = vec.back();
  vec.pop_back();
}
```

I see this essentially is a hand-coded version of the erase-remove idiom pointed out by Klaim ...

**2. A slower method that retains the original order of the elements:**

Step 1: Mark all vector elements to be deleted, i.e. with a special value. This has O(|indexes to delete|).

Step 2: Erase all marked elements using `v.erase( remove (v.begin(), v.end(), special_value), v.end() );`. This has O(|vector v|).

The total run time is thus O(|vector v|), assuming the index list is shorter than the vector.

**3. Another slower method that retains the original order of the elements:**

Use a predicate and remove if as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487742/280314 . To make this efficient and respecting the requirement of 
not "sorting then linearly erasing with an offset", my idea is to implement the predicate using a hash table and adjust the indexes stored in the hash table as the deletion proceeds on returning true, as Klaim suggested.

Comment: What if the last element is one of those scheduled for deletion?

Comment: Then swapping with itself is a no-op and `pop_back` still does the right thing.

Comment: The order of the indices isn't known according to the OP

Comment: This will reorder the vector, which might not be what you want.

Comment: HUH? Say that given a vector of 10 items, and I want to delete slot 5: I now Assign slot 5 with the value in slot 10, and delete slot 10? How is that supposed to be the correct answer? It's not.

Comment: @C Johnson: this is the correct answer if the order of the remaining elements doesn't matter. If it does matter, then you need more work to retain the order.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck
The issue due to which this could cause significant trouble is that some may attempt to use this with an index iterator. If you "erase" the last element, you can't increment your index iterator that cycle and instead need to repeat the process with the same index.

Comment: The method 1 in this answer has a bug!! (When the last item is marked to be deleted, it will be switched to the previous element's position, and then the total length of vector is shortened). For example, you have a vector 0,3,2,4,1,5,6, you want to delete 1,3,5 (indecies) element (which would be 3,4,5), however, the bug occurs that "5" will not be deleted!

Comment: @Pengyao Deleting the last element using method 1 works too. This was discussed in the first four comments, please have a look.

Comment: @PeterG. It does not work in my example though. Please work through my example. Number 4 would be scheduled for deletion before the last element at that time, which is number 5. Therefore 5 is switched to the position of 4, before it gets scheduled for deletion.

Comment: @Pengyao When deleting multiple elements by index, the indices to be deleted have to be processed in descending order so that indices that are yet to be deleted are still valid. This was meant by "If you start erasing from the back, all precomputed indexes will be correct." in the description of method 1.

Comment: Is there detailed performance data on remove_if vs. a "swap + pop"? In my limited testing (GCC -02) I only saw ~1-3% difference in performance - but perhaps I made some kind of mistake.

Comment: @TylerShellberg I did a benchmark just now, using Hayai and a 21 length vector, media performance: swap+pop: 1397k it/s, erase+remove: 912k it/s (I mark the values to be deleted with std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()), erase+remove_if: 836k it/s.

Comment: Note that I only deleted 3 items in the benchmark, if I delete 9, then the performance is a bit closer: 1079k vs 777k vs 630k. So, 72% the speed with `remove` and it keeps the order, and the deletion order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 15):

Using a predicate and the algorithm remove_if you can achieve what you want : see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/

Don't forget to erase the item (see [remove-erase idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)).

Your predicate will simply hold the idx of each value to remove and decrease all indexes it keeps each time it returns true.

That said if you can afford just removing each object using the remove-erase idiom, just make your life simple by doing it.

Answer (score 10):

Erase the items backwards. In other words erase the highest index first, then next highest etc. You won't invalidate any previous iterators or indexes so you can just use the obvious approach of multiple erase calls.

Comment: I wrote though: (sorting then linearly erasing with an offset is not an option)

Comment: @Milo: unless there's a good reason to arbitrarily reject one of the better solutions, then it certainly is an option. Why can't you sort the indexes?

Answer (score 6):

I would move the elements which you *don't* want to erase to a temporary vector and then replace the original vector with this.

Comment: I don't think that is any faster than the remove-if idiom which moves retained elements to the front is a single pass and then truncates the vector. No extra memory allocation needed -- everything is done in a single pass.

Answer (score 5):

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487736/1182653) by Peter G. in variant one (the swap-and-pop technique) is the fastest when you do not need to preserve the order, here is the unmentioned alternative which maintains the order.

With C++17 and C++20 the removal of multiple elements from a vector is possible with standard algorithms. The run time is O(N * Log(N)) due to `std::stable_partition`. There are no external helper arrays, no excessive copying, everything is done inplace. Code is a "one-liner":

```
template <class T>
inline void erase_selected(std::vector<T>& v, const std::vector<int>& selection)
{
    v.resize(std::distance(
        v.begin(),
        std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(),
             [&selection, &v](const T& item) {
                  return !std::binary_search(
                      selection.begin(),
                      selection.end(),
                      static_cast<int>(static_cast<const T*>(&item) - &v[0]));
        })));
}
```

The code above assumes that `selection` vector is sorted (if it is not the case, `std::sort` over it does the job, obviously).

To break this down, let us declare a number of temporaries:

```
// We need an explicit item index of an element
// to see if it should be in the output or not
int itemIndex = 0;
// The checker lambda returns `true` if the element is in `selection`
auto filter = [&itemIndex, &sorted_sel](const T& item) {
    return !std::binary_search(
                      selection.begin(),
                      selection.end(),
                      itemIndex++);
};
```

This checker lambda is then fed to `std::stable_partition` algorithm which is guaranteed to call this lambda only once for each element in the original (unpermuted !) array `v`.

```
auto end_of_selected = std::stable_partition(
                           v.begin(),
                           v.end(),
                           filter);
```

The `end_of_selected` iterator points right after the last element which should remain in the output array, so we now can resize `v` down. To calculate the number of elements we use the `std::distance` to get `size_t` from two iterators.

```
v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), end_of_selected));
```

This is different from the code at the top (it uses `itemIndex` to keep track of the array element). To get rid of the `itemIndex`, we capture the reference to source array `v` and use pointer arithmetic to calculate `itemIndex` internally.

Over the years (on this and other similar sites) multiple solutions have been proposed, but usually they employ multiple "raw loops" with conditions and some erase/insert/push_back calls. The idea behind `stable_partition` is explained beautifully in this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA) by Sean Parent.

This [link](https://coderwall.com/p/jsxrdq/c-erase-elements-from-containers-by-indices) provides a similar solution (and it does not assume that `selection` is sorted - `std::find_if` instead of `std::binary_search` is used), but it also employs a helper (incremented) variable which disables the possibility to parallelize processing on larger arrays.

Starting from C++17, there is a new first argument to `std::stable_partition` (the `ExecutionPolicy`) which allows auto-parallelization of the algorithm, further reducing the run-time for big arrays. To make yourself believe this parallelization actually works, there is another [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hi5WnRNckm4) by Hartmut Kaiser explaining the internals.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
void DeleteAll(vector<int>& data, const vector<int>& deleteIndices)
{
    vector<bool> markedElements(data.size(), false);
    vector<int> tempBuffer;
    tempBuffer.reserve(data.size()-deleteIndices.size());

    for (vector<int>::const_iterator itDel = deleteIndices.begin(); itDel != deleteIndices.end(); itDel++)
        markedElements[*itDel] = true;

    for (size_t i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!markedElements[i])
            tempBuffer.push_back(data[i]);
    }
    data = tempBuffer;
}
```

It's an O(n) operation, no matter how many elements you delete. You could gain some efficiency by reordering the vector inline (but I think this way it's more readable).

Answer (score 1):

This is non-trival because as you delete elements from the vector, the indexes change.

```
[0] hi
[1] you
[2] foo

>> delete [1]
[0] hi
[1] foo
```

If you keep a counter of times you delete an element and if you have a **list of indexes you want to delete** in sorted order then:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int k : IndexesToDelete) {
  events.erase(events.begin()+ k + counter);
  counter -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, if the order of the remaining elements doesn't matter

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector< int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(-6);
    vec.push_back(3);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(7);
    vec.push_back(9);
    vec.push_back(14);
    vec.push_back(25);
    cout << "The elements befor " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) cout << vec[i] <<endl;
    vector< bool> toDeleted;
    int YesOrNo = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    {
        
        cout<<"You need to delete this element? "<<vec[i]<<", if yes enter 1 else enter 0"<<endl;
        cin>>YesOrNo;
        if(YesOrNo)
            toDeleted.push_back(true);
        else
            toDeleted.push_back(false);
    }
    //Deleting, beginning from the last element to the first one
    for(int i = toDeleted.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(toDeleted[i])
        {
            vec[i] = vec.back();
            vec.pop_back();
        }
    }
    cout << "The elements after" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) cout << vec[i] <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant solution in case you want to preserve the indices, the idea is to replace the values you want to delete with a special value that is guaranteed not be used anywhere, and then at the very end, you perform the erase itself:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

// marking 3 elements to be deleted
vec[2] = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();
vec[5] = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();
vec[3] = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();

// erase
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest()), vec.end());

// print values => 1 2 5 7 8 9
for (const auto& value : vec) std::cout << ' ' << value;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It's very quick if you delete a lot of elements because the deletion itself is happening only once. Items can also be deleted in any order that way.

If you use a a struct instead of an int, then you can still mark an element of that struct, for ex `dead=true` and then use `remove_if` instead of `remove` =>

```
struct MyObj
{
    int  x;
    bool dead = false;
};

std::vector<MyObj> objs = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}};
objs[2].dead = true;
objs[5].dead = true;
objs[3].dead = true;
objs.erase(std::remove_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(), [](const MyObj& obj) { return obj.dead; }), objs.end());

// print values => 1 2 5 7 8 9
for (const auto& obj : objs) std::cout << ' ' << obj.x;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

This one is a bit slower, around 80% the speed of the `remove`.